# Swift function returning an enum

Tags: function, swift, enums

I'm trying to learn Swift and I'm stuck to a very simple thing. How to write a function that returns an enum. The following code doesn't compile:

```
import Foundation

enum ​MyResponse​ {
    case Even (String, String)
    case Odd  (String)
}

func checkNumber(number : Int) -> My​Response // <---- Error message
{
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return MyResponse.Even(String(number), " is even")
    }

    return MyResponse.Odd("odd")
}

let v1 = checkNumber(1)

switch v1 {
    case .Even(arg1, arg2):
        println("\(arg1) --> \(arg2)")
    case .Odd(arg):
        println("\(arg)")
}
```

I get the error message "Use of undeclared type".

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to return enum value from a function.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyResponse` from line #3 is different from `My​Response` in line #8.  There is unprintable character between "My" and "Response" in line #8.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I saw.